# Why async blocks execution blocking main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app that uses `AFNetworking` for sending requests and after it finished downloading, it calls block where I create data models from JSON. During model initialization, there is async image loading with the following code

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
   NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downloadURL];
}
```

I know that `dataWithContentsOfURL:` is synchronous, and in accordance with https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:

> ... this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow
>   network...

But as it's executing asynchronously in other thread, it shouldn't block main thread. After some investigating, I found that starting from `URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` method that is placed inside of `AFURLSessionManager.m` has the following blocks hierarchy

```
URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: //1
    |
   dispatch_async(url_session_manager_processing_queue(), ^{  //2
   //url_session_manager_processing_queue() - this is the default queue
       |
      dispatch_group_async(url_session_manager_completion_group(), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ //3
          |
         //Inside of my callback
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ //4
            |
           NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:downloadURL];
```

If I set `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s `completionQueue` property:

```
_sharedClient.completionQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
```

Then `dispatch_group_sync ... //3` using Default queue, not main and main thread is not blocked. Can someone explain why without setting `completionQueue` property my main thread is blocked? (Stack trace showing `semaphore_wait_trap` in main thread)

Comment: Since you're using AFNetworking anyway why are you using that primitive synchronous method rather than the excellent asynchronous skills of the library??

Comment: @vadian This code was written by the other developer, so I have no idea why he did it in such way. Using AFNetworking instead of `dataWithContentsOfURL:` will help, but my goal is to understand why the main thread is blocked.

Comment: Look for better code or write it yourself ;-)